# String.Equals challenge in C#

Tags: c#

I wanted to make a statistics program for different languages...
BUT: I could not find an answer for the following block of codes!
Unfortunately the no variable does not increment at all!
Should it be at the String.Equals() method call?

```
String text = new String("// random text here!");

var textArray = text.ToCharArray(); 
for(int i=0;alphabet[i]!="0";i++){
    String letter = alphabet[i];

char EOF = (char)Int16.Parse("000A", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
    int no = 0;         

    // Count the occurences of letter!
    for(int j = 0;textArray[j]!=EOF;j++){
        int eq = (String.Equals(textArray[i].ToString(),letter)? 1 : 0 );
        no = no + eq;
    }
```

Thank you for your appreciation!

Comment: What is `alphabet`? (note you could probably do this a lot easier with linqs `GroupBy`)

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here - a short but *complete* example with sample input and expected/actual output would make it easier to help you. Additionally, you should learn about Unicode escapes for character literals, e.g. `char eof = '\u000a'`. Not that U+000A is an end of *file* character anyway...

Comment: your code should not even compile . `string()` does not take string.

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand what you are trying to achieve but just looking into your code I feel below code should refer variable j instead of i

```
String.Equals(textArray[i].ToString(),letter)
```

Change it to

```
String.Equals(textArray[j].ToString(),letter)
```